# python function return break in for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop

```py
def f():
  return break

for i in range(10):
    f()
```

```
File "<ipython-input-2-24d25cc18b48>", line 2
    return break
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how should I do

use function return berak in for loop

Comment: why did u say `return break`?. Your question is not useful

Comment: `break` is a reserved word

Comment: you can't return ```break```, ```break```is used to get off a loop or a function, by itself.

Comment: check this : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing what you want to do is something like this:

```
def f():
  return True

for i in range(10):
    if f():
        break
```